# Symfony log file permissions on docker

Tags: nginx, docker, symfony

I have a similar configuration with other project, and It run good. But, this project get problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/docker/test-project/var/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/docker/test-project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107 Stack trace: #0 /home/docker/test-project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1 /home/docker/test-project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/FingersCrossedHandler.php(122): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2 /home/docker/test-project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336): Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array) #3 /home/docker/test-project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(643): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(500, 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array) #4 /home/docker/test-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php(89): Monolog\Logger->critical('Uncaught PHP Ex. in /home/docker/test-project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107

I tried: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html and I don't get a good result

Comment: Have you tried to read the error message?

Comment: You have a mounted volume ? Or copy data in container?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a nginx tag, maybe you are also using nginx as the web server, if so, you might need to do some configuration there:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Your question and setup should be described in your question. If you can edit and update, that would be good.

Answer (score 0):

There is log file permission problem. Docker has not support `setfacl` with default filesystem driver.

Try this solution as described in [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html):
change the umask so that the cache and log directories are group-writable or world-writable (depending if the web server user and the command line user are in the same group or not). To achieve this, put the following line at the beginning of the bin/console, web/app.php and web/app_dev.php files:

```
umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run this command into project directory:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
```

Comment: This command only defines an environment variable, so it cannot fix anything.

Comment: An env var **can** have effect and solve thing. In the above case, this resembles [Symfony's doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd). I don't know if it is the correct solution, but for sure **it can fix problems**, since it seems like it's setting Apache for being able to write to logs; that is the problem of the OP.